# Trying to locate the source of a runtime error in my code?

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

hoping someone can point to where my issue is with my code. I'm getting `runtime error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set` with the following code:

```
Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim htmldoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim htmlinput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim htmlbuttons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

'see window and navigate to website 
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "WEBSITE"
    
'wait for brower to load
Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop
    
'enters username and password
Set htmldoc = ie.document
Set htmlinput = htmldoc.getElementById("USER")
htmlinput.Value = "USER1"
Set htmlinput = htmldoc.getElementById("PASSWORD")
htmlinput.Value = "PASS1"

'finds form > submit button (under class = "LoginSubmit")
htmldoc.forms(0).submit
```

When I try to debug, `htmlinput.Value = "USER` is highlighted. I should mention that the site loads, and accepts user/password properly, but I get the error after successfully logging in.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Is there a certain line that gives the error?

Comment: When I debug it highlights htmlinput.Value = "USER1"

Comment: And does it give you a error code reason? Help us help you. This info should be included in your question already

Comment: 1) You have tried to access too soon (likely) 2) wrong id or element doesn't exist 3) element is in an iframe (common)

Comment: It appears that it is most likely to do with accessing too quickly- what would you recommend I add?

Comment: set htmlinput.Value = "USER" fixes the problem?

Comment: Looks like there are more ready states you need to complete before stepping through the code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36069332/getelementbyid-vba-excel-not-working

Comment: @virxen no, that doesn't fix it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53911498/wait-until-specific-elements-loaded